# How to get mouse coordinates as a variable?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk


field = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]


class Game:
    def click_coordinates(event):
        x = str(event.x)
        y = str(event.y)
        print(x, y)

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Tic Tac Toe")
    root.geometry("304x304")
    my_canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, background="black")
    my_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0)
    my_canvas.create_line(100, 0, 100, 305, fill="white", width=3)
    my_canvas.create_line(200, 0, 200, 305, fill="white", width=3)
    my_canvas.create_line(0, 100, 305, 100, fill="white", width=3)
    my_canvas.create_line(0, 200, 305, 200, fill="white", width=3)
    my_canvas.bind("<Button-1>", click_coordinates)

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    game = Game()
```

My problem is that I want to return the mouse coordinates as a variable.
I tried to write:

```
def click_coordinates(event):
    x = str(event.x)
    y = str(event.y)
    mouse = x + ":" + y
    return mouse
```

But I have no idea how I can reach this variable with other functions. If I want to call another function from the `click_coordinates()` function, I get an error that the name of the new function I want to call is not defined. It seems like I can only print the coordinates.

Comment: are you trying to save them as an attribute in your class?

Comment: Return them? Return them _where_? You can't return values from a callback. Or more correctly, you can return something but the code that runs the callback ignores what is returned in most cases.

Comment: You will need to make your callback function, `click_coordinates()`, store the information somewhere tthat he rest of your application can access, such as a list of some kind or some other type of container object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set a global or instance variable if you want to access the values outside of the callback. Since you are using a class (though, using it incorrectly<sup>1</sup>), an instance variable is the natural choice:

Example:

```
def click_coordinates(self, event):
    self.last_x = event.x
    self.last_y = event.y
```

You can then reference `self.last_x` and `self.last_y` anywhere else in your object. It would be a good idea to initialize these to `None` in the `__init__` of the class:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.last_x = self.last_y = None
        ...
```

---

<sup>1</sup> You should move all of the code inside `__init__` rather than directly under `class Game`. Also, `click_coordinates` needs a `self` argument and should be referenced as `self.click_coordinates`.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        ...
        my_canvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.click_coordinates)

    def click_coordinates(self, event):
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I moved the Code under the __init__ and its working now. Its my first time working with classes.

Answer (score 0):

i just want to advise you that you would better replace canvas by buttons,im sure that it will be easier because buttons have command, you better do something like this:

```
`b1=Button(win,font=("Arial Bold", 
50),width=3,bg='white',fg='SteelBlue',command=add1)
lst
b1.grid(row=2,column=1)
b2=Button(win,font=("Arial Bold", 50),width=3,bg='white',fg='SteelBlue',command=add2)
lst
b2.grid(row=2,column=2)
b3=Button(win,font=("Arial Bold", 50),width=3,bg='white',fg='SteelBlue',command=add3)
lst
b3.grid(row=2,column=3)
b4=Button(win,font=("Arial Bold", 50),width=3,bg='white',fg='SteelBlue',command=add4)
lst
b4.grid(row=3,column=1)
b5=Button(win,font=("Arial Bold", 50),width=3,bg='white',fg='SteelBlue',command=add5)
lst
b5.grid(row=3,column=2)
b6=Button(win,font=("Arial Bold", 50),width=3,bg='white',fg='SteelBlue',command=add6)
lst
b6.grid(row=3,column=3)
b7=Button(win,font=("Arial Bold", 50),width=3,bg='white',fg='SteelBlue',command=add7)
lst
b7.grid(row=4,column=1)
b8=Button(win,font=("Arial Bold", 50),width=3,bg='white',fg='SteelBlue',command=add8)
lst
b8.grid(row=4,column=2)
b9=Button(win,font=("Arial Bold", 50),width=3,bg='white',fg='SteelBlue',command=add9)
lst
b9.grid(row=4,column=3)`
```

and then define 9 functions and if you want to play against the computer or against another player(not good because it is very easy) and if you want to be robust just play around this code -_- .